# Spying on an imported function that calls another function in Jest

Tags: ecmascript-6, jestjs

I'm trying to spy on a function that's called by another function, both of which reside in an external file and imported.

Funcs.spec.js:

```
import * as Funcs from './Funcs'
describe('funcA', () => {
    it('calls funcB', () => {
        jest.spyOn(Funcs, 'funcB')
        Funcs.funcA()
        expect(Funcs.funcB).toHaveBeenCalled()
    }
}
```

Funcs.js:

```
export const funcA = () => {
    funcB()
}
export const funcB = () => {}
```

For some reason the spy is not respected in scope of Funcs.js. What can I do to spy on funcB so I know funcA has called it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Only methods can be spied. There is no way to spy on `funcB` if it's called directly like `funcB()` within same module.

In order for exported function to be spied or mocked, `funcA` and `funcB` should reside in different modules.

This allows to spy on `funcB` in *transpiled* ES module (module object is read-only in native ESM):

```
import { funcB } from './b';

export const funcA = () => {
    funcB()
}
```

Due to that module imports are representations of modules, this is transpiled to:

```
var _b = require('./b');

var funcA = exports.funcA = function funcA() {
    (0, _b.funcB)();
};
```

Where `funcB` method is tied to `_b` module object, so it's possible to spy on it.

Comment: This is correct, but incomplete. What the OP asks (to test functions exported in the same file) can be achieved without splitting into different files/modules. If you are curious to know how check my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50856001/220272).

Comment: @a--m *without splitting into different files/modules* - this wasn't listed as a requirement. The code needs to be refactored to be more testable, I just suggested an idiomatic way to improve the testability. This is a trade-off that depends on how crucial is to spy on funcB; could be unnecessary. Yes, it's possible with CJS modules like you suggested, but it seems a bit too much IMO. Since the context for this code is unknown, there's no guarantee that CJS modules are appropriate or supported in the application (they also don't support tree-shaking).

Comment: Understood. I agree with your arguments about splitting as an improvement for testing as a generic rule. But due to the fact that the OP states that *both of which reside in an external file and imported* I thought that including a solution for this specific requirement its also important. As matter of fact what we are discussing here is also stated on the jest issue I referred ;)

Answer (score 5):

The problem you describe is referenced on a [jest issue](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/1075#issuecomment-221771095).

A possible solution to your problem (if you want to keep the functions inside the same file) is to use CommonJS, consider the following example:

*fns.js*

```
exports.funcA = () => {
  exports.funcB();
};
exports.funcB = () => {};
```

*fns.spec.js*

```
const fns = require("./fns");

describe("funcA", () => {
  it("calls funcB", () => {
    fns.funcB = jest.fn();
    fns.funcA();
    expect(fns.funcB).toBeCalled();
  });
});
```