# Jest testing a function with no return

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

I am in the process of unit testing a function using Jest that merely passes on its parameters to another function by calling it and has no return.

I have googled and tried a bunch of suggested mock implementations, but can't seem to get it to work.

**Imported File:**

```
export const firstFunc = (dataObj) => {
  secondFunc('anything', dataObj)
}

export const secondFunc = (str, dataObj) => {
  // Does something with the dataObj but also doesn't return anything.
}
```

Essentially what I want to test for is that `firstFunc` calls `secondFunc`, but am not able to get it to work.

Thank you in advance. Also, open to suggestions for any other tests that I could run in this situation.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I understood your problem, you could have two solutions.

Firstly, add return value after calling function, and export it to tests.

Secondly, you could use sinon js with jest.

[Spying on an imported function that calls another function in Jest](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50854440/9128015)