# How to call an exported function internally in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, export

I am trying to call an exported function inside the nodejs module.

```
exports.sayHello = function (msg) {
 console.log(msg) 
}

function run(msg) {
  this.sayHello(msg);
}

run("hello");
```

when I run this script I got **TypeError: this.sayHello is not a function**

Comment: I'm curious why after assigning a function to `exports.sayHello`, it did not occur to you to call it via `exports.sayHello()`?  That's where you assigned the function, that's where you can access it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply declare it separately from exporting it (and don't use `this` when calling it, you haven't attached it to an object):

```
function sayHello(msg) {
 console.log(msg) 
}
exports.sayHello = sayHello;

function run(msg) {
  sayHello(msg);
}

run("hello");
```

That said, you **could** call it via `exports`:

```
exports.sayHello = function (msg) {
 console.log(msg) 
}

function run(msg) {
  exports.sayHello(msg); // <===
}

run("hello");
```

...but that seems a bit roundabout to me, though I'm told it can help with testing, such as [in this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50854440/spying-on-an-imported-function-that-calls-another-function-in-jest).

Comment: This is not a roundabout if it serves a purpose, e.g. improves testability.

Comment: If module exports are consistently called as `exports` methods, it's possible to spy or mock them. This improves testability in cases like this one, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50854440/spying-on-an-imported-function-that-calls-another-function-in-jest . Of course, this won't work for this particular `run` function.

Comment: @estus - I think you probably have more experience with that than I do. I've updated that comment, thanks!