# How can I stub the following function in sinon?

Tags: node.js, typescript, mocha.js, sinon

My test function is as follows:

```
const testLibrary = require("./test");

describe("Top Test", function() {

    it("should test function", function(done) {
        testLibrary.print();
        done();

    });


});
```

test.ts has the following two functions:

```
export function stubMe() {
    console.log("original function");
}

export function print() {
    stubMe();
}
```

When I run the test, it prints: 'original function'

I now try to stub my test as follows:

```
const testLibrary = require("./test");


const sinon = require("sinon");

const stubMe = sinon.stub(testLibrary, "stubMe");
stubMe.yields();

describe("Top Test", function() {

    it("should test function", function(done) {
        testLibrary.print();
        done();

    });


});
```

My test function still prints 'original function' indicating that the function hasn't been stubbed.

How do I stub the stubMe function?

Update:

I have modified my code based on Ankit's solution below to:

```
  const sinon = require("sinon");
  const testLibrary = require("./test");

  testLibrary.stubMe();

  const stubMe = new sinon.stub(testLibrary, "stubMe").callsFake(function () {
    console.log("console from stub");
  });

  testLibrary.stubMe();


  describe("Top Test", function () {

    it("should test function", function (done) {
      testLibrary.print();
      done();

    });

  });
```

Oddly, this prints:

```
original function
console from stub


  Top Test
original function
```

Why does the stub revert during the test?

Comment: Because in one case you're calling `testLibrary.stubMe()` and in another case you're calling `stubMe()`. This is what the answer says.

Answer (score 0):

Use `callsFake()` instead of `yields()` like:

```
 const testLibrary = require('./test');

  const sinon = require('sinon');

  const stubMe = new sinon.stub(testLibrary, 'stubMe');
  stubMe.callsFake(function () {
    console.log('console from stub');
  });

  describe('Top Test', function () {

    it('should test function', function (done) {
      testLibrary.print();
      done();

    });

  });
```

Here is the output for the above test:
[image]

Comment: It's still printing 'original function'

Comment: @Hoa it works for me in my local. What is the version of sinon?

Comment: 6.0.1 - what version are you using?

Comment: I am using `"sinon": "4.2.1"` @Hoa

Comment: Getting a strange result - see main edited question. Any idea why that behaviour is occurring?

Comment: You won't physically be able to stub stubMe in a situation like this one. You didn't list `test` file, but it should differ from the OP.

Comment: @Hoa you are also calling `testLibrary.stubMe();` in your test file before the test actually executes. That is why you get that first `console.log` in the console as `original function`

Answer (score 0):

There is no way how the function can be spied or mocked. `stubMe` is referred directly in same module.

As explained in [related Jest question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50854440/spying-on-an-imported-function-that-calls-another-function-in-jest/50855968#50855968), a way to improve testability is to move functions to different modules:

```
// one module
export function stubMe() {
    console.log("original function");
}

// another module
import { stubMe } from '...';
export function print() {
    stubMe();
}
```

In this case `testLibrary.stubMe` can be spied or mocked, but only if non-native ES modules are in use, because ES module exports are read-only in native implementation.