# export.something Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

Here is a code snippet

```
 body.user_id = userObj._id;

          exports.inFCID(conn, obj.fcid, body, fcid, 0).then(function (r) {

            exports.getUserById(conn, body.user_id).then(function (u) {
              console.log("after getuserbyid", u);
```

Here I am sort of didn't understand why user have done something like

```
  exports.inFCID(conn, obj.fcid, body, fcid, 0).then(function (r
```

of to be precise what does it do? I have previously encounter things like module.exports and export default statement ( export something statements) but this seems to be new.. Can someone explain me what this snippets would normally do? Ignoring what is inside those functions (inFCID) or what does export.something do in middle of the code..

Comment: that's very weird code and it is certainly not exporting anyting. It would only make any sense if exports had such properties assigned to it in another section in the same module. Even if that's the case, it is very confusing and should be refactored

Comment: Same as `module.exports`, the method can be exported from any point in a file https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-module-exports-exports-node-js/. But, in this case, the case doesn't seem to be the same. Here, more than one thing is exporting.

Comment: Those are invocations of previously assigned exports. Otherwise they're going to blow up. They don't export anything themselves

Answer (score 0):

It's expected that `inFCID` export is defined in this module as well:

```
exports.inFCID = function inFCID (...) {...};
```

When an export is defined as function expression, `inFCID` function is not available as `inFCID`  but as `exports.inFCID`.

Referring exported functions as `exports.inFCID` inside module is a common recipe to improve testability in CommonJS modules; the same recipe won't work with ESM; a module needs to be separated when used with ES modules, as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50855968/3731501). Module exports can be spied or mocked outside the module:

```
const foo = require('foo');
...
spyOn(foo, 'inFCID');
foo.bar();
expect(foo.inFCID).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

This would be impossible if `inFCID(...)` was referred directly.

Answer (score 0):

`exports` is a regular object.

If you have a code like this:

```
function test() {}

module.exports.test = test
```

Then nodejs will convert it into something like this:

```
function moduleInvocation(module, exports) { 
  function test() {}
  module.exports.test = test
}

// a rough dummy code, to illustrat what node does on require
function require(moduleName) {
   var module = { exports : {} };

   //
   //  some code that loades `moduleName` and wraps it into `moduleInvocation`
   //

   moduleInvocation(module, module.exports)

   return module;
}
```

So if someone writes `exports.inFCID()` then it is not different to:

```
var obj = {};
obj.inFCID = function() {}

obj.inFCID();
```

But it does not make any sense to write it that way except if you compose the `exports` of the module out of the content of some sub files.