# Jest - Mocking a React Component's dependency which returns a Promise

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mocha.js, jestjs, create-react-app

I have a React component with the following dependency:

```
import { fetchUsers } from '../../api/';
```

This is utility function that returns a Promise.

When attempting to mock this using Jest, I've been unable to do this on a per test basis within a `describe()`.

The only way I've been able to mock `fetchUsers` is to `jest.mock()` at the top of the file for the entire test suite.

```
import x from './x'

jest.mock('../../../../src/api/', () => ({
    fetchUsers: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({ users: [] })),
}));
```

This doesn't suit as I need to test the `.then()` (Promise.resolve) and the `.catch` (Promise.reject) in different tests. With the above, I can only test the `.then()`

Does anyone know how to use Jest to mock a React Component's dependency which returns a promise on a per test basis?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Jest mock functions can change implementation:

```
jest.mock('../../../../src/api/', () => ({
    fetchUsers: jest.fn()
}));

...
const { fetchUsers } = require('../../../../src/api/');
fetchUsers.mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve({ users: [] }));
// do something that calls fetchUsers
```

As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50855968/3731501), it's also possible to mock a property on transpiled `*` import any time due to how ES modules work:

```
import * as api from '../../../../src/api/';

...
jest.spyOn(api, 'fetchUsers').mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve({ users: [] }));
// do something that calls fetchUsers
```

Comment: Hi @estus, I was able to get the jest.mock()/require() method working but was unable to get the import/spyOn() method working... getting the error... Cannot set property fetchUsers of #<Object> which has only a getter... do you know why this could be?

Comment: @JamesGallagher This is a known issue, https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/4039 . This depends on how modules are configured. It looks like they aren't configured properly in create-react-app Jest setup, I would expect them to be CJS in Jest while they are not. I guess the second solution doesn't fit your setup.