# Jestjs how to test function being called inside another function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-test-renderer

For testing I use jest and react-test-renderer. It should be simple to test, however I have a hard time finding the proper example. I have tried to do something like that (in general I keep the functions in separate files):

utils.js

```
export const childFunction = () => 'something';    
const parentFunction = () => childFunction();
export default parentFunction;
```

utils.test.js

```
import parentFunction from './utils.js';


it('childFunction should be called', () => {
 const childFunction = jest.fn();
 parentFunction();
 expect(childFunction).toBeCalled();
})
```

The fragment *const childFunction = jest.fn();* definitely won't work. While calling, parentFunction's body cares only about its own scope. But it also won't work if I import childFunction and do *jest.mock(childFunction)*, because jest.mock needs a string, a url to a module, and not the function itself.

The example above doesn't work and I'm searching for an alternative. However this works after rendering the component with ShallowRenderer. And I'd like to achieve a similar behaviour with a function nested inside another function.

```
class Component extends React.Component {
 componentDidMount() {parentFunction()}
 render() {...}
}

const renderer = new ShallowRenderer();
describe("testing parentFunction", () => {
  renderer.render(<Component/>);
  it("parentFunction should be called", () => {
    expect(parentFunction).toBeCalled();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's no way to spy on function call if a function isn't called as object method.

As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50855968/3731501), due to how ES modules work, it's possible to spy or mock a function only if it was exported from a module and is used in another module. This way it can be spied on module `*` object, or be mocked with `jest.mock`.

If this isn't the case, it should be tested indirectly:

```
expect(childFunction()).toBe('something');
expect(parentFunction()).toBe('something');
```

Comment: Yup, it seems that I can forget watching if a function has been called somewhere that is not a component. It's valuable to know I wanted to do the impossible thing. :)

Answer (score 10):

not sure if this will help but it may give you ideas.

first, the example above:

```
// this needs to be stubbed
// const childFunction = () => 'something';
const childFunction = jest.fn();

const parentFunction = () => childFunction();

it('childFunction should be called', () => {
    parentFunction();
    expect(childFunction).toHaveBeenCalled();
}
```

this is a somewhat contrived example as it's unlikely that `childFunction` is exported so you cannot get a reference to it and mock/stub it.

one workaround you have would be to move it out into its own method

```
class Component extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.parentFunction();
  }
  parentFunction() {
    parentFunction(); // from elsewhere
  }
  render() {...}
}
```

This allows you to create a puncture and spy on the Component proto.

eg

```
const spy = jest.spyOn(Component.prototype, 'parentFunction');

// ... mount so lifecycle runs... 
expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled(); // and clear the spy mocks after!
```

it may be better to mock the module

eg you have utils.js used by your component that does:

```
export function parentFunction(){ console.log('parent'); }
```

component.js does:

```
import { parentFunction } from './utils';
```

you could in your tests do:

```
const utils = require('./utils');
utils.parentFunction = jest.fn();
import Component from './component';
// later
expect(utils.parentFunction).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

as you can see, many possible ways to go, though I am not sure on the value of that test, you should probably test the output / functionality of the component rather than it had called, having something run on `componentDidMount` is a given and would only break if somebody converted to functional or changed the lifecycle name.

Comment: Thanks for reply. However, checking if parentFunction has been called is not an issue here, but checking if childFunction inside parentFunction was called. And I do export my child function, just for the test's sake. I'll edit my question for it to show how my file structure looks like.