# Jest check when async function gets called

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

I'm trying to test whether an async function (fire and forget) gets called.

`Content.js`

```
  export async function fireAndForgetFunction() {
    ...  
  }

  export async function getData() {
    ...
    fireAndForgetFunction()
    return true;
  }
```

I would like to test if `fireAndForgetFunction` has been called more than once.

`Current test`

```
  import * as ContentFetch from '../Content';

  const { getData } = ContentFetch;
  const { fireAndForgetFunction } = ContentFetch;

  it('test',async () => {
    const spy = jest.spyOn(ContentFetch, 'fireAndForgetFunction');

    await getData();

    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  })
```

The test result to an error saying

```
    Expected number of calls: >= 1
    Received number of calls:    0
```

How could I do this test?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jestjs how to test function being called inside another function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52650367/jestjs-how-to-test-function-being-called-inside-another-function)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to await for `fireAndForgetFunction` in `getData()`, which I assume is the case, then providing a mock implementation of `fireAndForgetFunction` when creating the spy is your best option:

```
it('test', (done) => {
    const spy = jest.spyOn(ContentFetch, 'fireAndForgetFunction')
        .mockImplementation(() => {
          expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
          done();
        })
    getData();
})
```